# calling a method from another method is throwing java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name

Tags: groovy

Running the groovy script using the GroovyScriptEngine. Here is the groovy file created.

BasePayCalculation.groovy

```
return calculate()

def calculate() {
    def currentPay = currentPay
    currentPay = normalize(currentPay);
    // Current pay cannot be zero
    if (currentPay == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Current pay is zero")
    }
}


def normalize(def it) {
    if (it == null) 
        return 0
    else
        return it
}
```

Running this from the application, getting

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "cds:BasePayCalculation$normalize$0" in class file cds:BasePayCalculation$normalize$0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.define(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts$1.run(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts$1.run(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:84)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.defineClassAndGetConstructor(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteGenerator.compilePogoMethod(CallSiteGenerator.java:217)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.createPogoMetaMethodSite(CachedMethod.java:228)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.createCachedMethodSite(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.createPogoMetaMethodSite(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:188)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createPogoCallCurrentSite(MetaClassImpl.java:3122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallCurrentSite(CallSiteArray.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at cds:BasePayCalculation.calculate(cds:BasePayCalculation.groovy:20)
    at cds:BasePayCalculation.run(cds:BasePayCalculation.groovy:16)
    at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine.run(GroovyScriptEngine.java:551)
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

#### Extra info from below:

- Running from tomcat using webapplication.
- Groovy 2.1.1.
- Running this using code

  ```
  Binding params = new Binding()
  if (context != null) {
    for (String key : context.keySet()) {
      Object param = context.get(key);
      params.setVariable(key, param);
    }
  }
  long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
  Object object = engine.run(name, params);
  ```

Java Version 1.6
tomcat version 6.0.24

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you running this?  (can you post the code?)  What version of Groovy?

Comment: Running from tomcat using webapplication. Groovy 2.1.1. Running this using 'Binding params = new Binding();
  if (context != null) {
   for (String key : context.keySet()) {
    Object param = context.get(key);
    params.setVariable(key, param);
   }
  }
  long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
  Object object = engine.run(name, params);'

Comment: Can you add a bit more code from how are you running? I tried running this using `GroovyShell` and it worked fine

Comment: I'm calling the groovy script using GroovyScriptEngine. Engine.run(groovyname, bindingparams); Let me know what more information is needed. Thanks

Comment: @Raj, did you tried/can you try running outside tomcat? I made a example using scripts and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that groovy declares a class with the same name as the script that is run and therefore the script name [needs to be a valid identifier from JVM perspective](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-505). In this case I presume, the problem is the ":" character.